# SQALE plugin for sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I was trying to add SQALE plugin for SonarQube. I was doing some research and there was a SonarSource blog (https://blog.sonarsource.com/sqale-the-ultimate-quality-model-to-assess-technical-debt) talks about a commercial SQALE plugin for Sonar, but the link to the plugin gives a 404.

Is there any other documentation for SQALE plugin or is it something fully out from Sonar?, the official SQALE website still refers Sonar for implementation.

Comment: The SQUALE plugin is very old. What the SonarQube version you use?

Comment: It is SonarQube 6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQALE plugin does not exist any longer. The management of technical debt has been incorporated as a core concept in SonarQube. As such, you will see the amount of technical debt display on the home page of each project analysed by SonarQube.

You will also find the relevant metrics on the SonarQube official documentation: https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/technical-debt.html